# What is difference between left and right in Gas Estimates of Remix

Tags: gas

Gas Estimates:
Creation: 26137 + 1082400

what is difference between left one and right one?
[image]

I wonder this.
Please enlighten me.
I guess right one is about contract and left one is others like temporary memory;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this refers to

```
Transaction cost:26137  gas. // the cost for sending the contract to the blockchain
Execution cost:1082400  gas  // the cost of the VM use (the opcodes).
```

more details : [What is the difference between transaction cost and execution cost in browser solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-browser-so)