# How to whitelist up to 50k addresses in a single contract?

Tags: solidity, gas, remix, gas-estimate

What is the best practice in whitelisting a large amount of addresses in a contract. For example, if I wanted to include 50k addresses into a mapping that will reflect `true` for only the 50k addresses, would this be the optimal way? How much would this cost, per address?

```
mapping (address => bool) userAddr;

function whitelistAddress (address user) onlyOwner { userAddr[user] = true; }
```

Including 50k addresses hardcoded into the contract would hit the block gas limit, no doubt. How do I calculate exactly how much this would cost

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Quick Lower Bound**

You can put a lower bound on the cost, because each address will include one SSTORE, at the very least. So the cost to hard-code 50k addresses, at 20 kgas each would be more than 1 Gigagas total. The latest block limit is 6.7 Megagas. It will not fit, by a long shot.

> Gsset - 20000 gas - Paid for an SSTORE operation when the storage value is set to non-zero from zero

source: [Yellow Paper, Appendix G](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

---

**Practical Cost**

So let's look at the practical cost of incrementally adding whitelist addresses. [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org) is an excellent way to quickly estimate gas costs for your function.

Using this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Owned {
    address owner;

    function Owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}
contract Whitelist is Owned {
    mapping (address => bool) userAddr;

    function whitelistAddress (address user) onlyOwner {
        userAddr[user] = true;
    }
}
```

I ran the function this way:

1. Choose the "Javascript VM" Environment
2. Click [Create] under Whitelist on the right bar
3. Enter `"0x5B2063246F2191f18F2675ceDB8b28102e957458"` next to the [whitelistAddress] button
4. Click the [whitelistAddress] button

Running `whitelistAddress(...)` results in: 
`Transaction cost: 43464 gas`

Total cost: `50k transactions * 43k gas ~= 2 Gigagas`

At current "[Safe Low](http://ethgasstation.info/)" costs of 0.5 gwei , that equates to about 1 ether of total gas costs.

---

**Batching for Marginal Improvement**

Some of that call to add a whitelisted address is overhead: the original function call, checking the owner, etc. Let's find out how much.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Whitelist is Owned {
    mapping (address => bool) userAddr;

    function whitelistAddress (address[] users) onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            userAddr[users[i]] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this with a list of four addresses costs 109833 gas, resulting in a per-address cost of only 27458.25 gas. We won't do much better than that on an explicit whitelist, since the lower bound is 20k gas per address.

Using this method, the total ether cost at the Safe Low price has dropped to about:

`50k addresses * 27k gas * 0.5 gigawei ~= 0.7 Ether`

---

**Weirder Alternatives**

Maybe you don't really have a whitelist, maybe it's a blacklist or a guest list where the occasional false positive isn't too bad. Then a bloom filter could be a reasonable solution. Tuning the bloom filter requires knowing too much about your specific use case, but it could easily reduce the total cost by 1,000x or 10,000x.

Comment: Really wonderful answer. It all makes sense, so thank you, though I do have one question. When copying that first block of code into Remix, I see a `Transaction cost: 20784 gas`, as opposed to the `Transaction cost: 43464 gas`, as you stated. I am looking at Gas Estimates -> External -> whitelistAddress(address). Is there another place that the gas is estimated?

Comment: I'm not sure how remix generates that estimate. I just ran the transaction by clicking the [whitelistAddress] button after entering "0x5B2063246F2191f18F2675ceDB8b28102e957458" next to it. I'll edit the answer to add those steps.

Comment: You need to enter the address *with* the double-quotes. The input box expects JSON-encoded content.

Comment: When you get the gas from that, can you simply ignore the "execution cost"? When does that come into play? I see the 43464 now, but there is also the execution cost.

Comment: Scratch that, [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-browser-so) answered it. Thank you.

Comment: Would a similar approach be employed for whitelist addresses with individual contribution caps?

Comment: Classic Bloom filter will not work. If there is any chance of a false positive, an attacker can just keep generating addresses till they hit one.

Answer (score 3):

There are some more modern alternatives which are essential to consider now that gas is so much higher.

### Merkle root based whitelist (low cost, moderate flexibility)

Use all of the addresses on your list to generate a Merkle tree. Then have the user submit their proof (can serve on front-end, not sensitive since only the address holder can use their proof), along with the mint call.

I consider this medium flexibility because if you want to change the list at all you have to update the root on chain.

Generation code (js)

```
      const newMerkle = new MerkleTree(
        ['0x1...', '0x2...'].map((token: string) => hashToken(token)),
        keccak256,
        {
          duplicateOdd: false,
          hashLeaves: false,
          isBitcoinTree: false,
          sortLeaves: false,
          sortPairs: true,
          sort: false,
        }
      )

export function hashToken(account: string) {
  return Buffer.from(ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["address"], [account]).slice(2), "hex");
}
```

Verification code (solidity)

```
    function mintPresale(uint256 _quantity, bytes32[] calldata _proof)
        external
        payable
    {
        require(_verify(_leaf(msg.sender), _proof), "Invalid merkle proof");
        _mint(_quantity, msg.sender);
    }
```

```
    function _verify(bytes32 leaf_, bytes32[] memory _proof)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        return MerkleProof.verify(_proof, root, leaf_);
    }
```

This snippet uses code from OpenZeppelin Merkle Proof library and merkletreejs

### Signature based whitelist (minimal cost, highly flexible)

Generate signatures ahead of time or live on a back end and serve them to the user to include in their mint call. These are also not sensitive so they can be served on the front end without any auth.

Signing code (typescript)

```
export default async function signWhitelist(
    chainId: number,
    contractAddress: string,
    whitelistKey: SignerWithAddress,
    mintingAddress: string,
    nonce: number
) {
    const domain = {
        name: '[YOUR_CONTRACT_NAME}',
        version: '1',
        chainId,
        verifyingContract: contractAddress,
    }

    const types = {
        Minter: [
            { name: 'wallet', type: 'address' },
            { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
        ],
    }

    const sig = await whitelistKey._signTypedData(domain, types, {
        wallet: mintingAddress,
        nonce,
    })

    return sig
}
```

Verifying code (Solidity)

```
    modifier requiresWhitelist(
        bytes calldata signature,
        uint256 nonce
    ) {
        // Verify EIP-712 signature by recreating the data structure
        // that we signed on the client side, and then using that to recover
        // the address that signed the signature for this data.
        bytes32 structHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(MINTER_TYPEHASH, msg.sender, nonce)
        );
        bytes32 digest = toTypedMessageHash(structHash); /*Calculate EIP712 digest*/
        require(!signatureUsed[digest], "signature used");
        signatureUsed[digest] = true;
        // Use the recover method to see what address was used to create
        // the signature on this data.
        // Note that if the digest doesn't exactly match what was signed we'll
        // get a random recovered address.
        address recoveredAddress = digest.recover(signature);
        require(
            hasRole(WHITELISTING_ROLE, recoveredAddress),
            "Invalid Signature"
        );
        _;
    }
```

These snippets are adapted from this repo: https://github.com/msfeldstein/EIP712-whitelisting/blob/main/contracts/EIP712Whitelisting.sol

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty easy. you do it like this. via signatures. you need a backend....

function matchAddresSigner(bytes32 hash, bytes memory signature) private view returns (bool) {
return _signerAddress == hash.recover(signature);
}

with

require(matchAddresSigner(hash, sig), "no direct mint");

....

Comment: can you please explain a bit how to do this. how can this be used to whitelist address?