# What is the cheapest and most efficient way to send data to a struct, and why?

Tags: storage, arrays, struct, gas-price

I'm struggling to find which way to send data to a struct is cheaper and most efficient. I came up with these 2 different styles:

```
struct Database
{
   string name;
   string addressPerson; 
}

mapping (string => Database) idToDatabase;

function setPerson(string _id, string _name, string _address) external {
   Database storage person = idToDatabase[_id];
   person.name = _name;
   person.addressPerson = _address;
}
```

and

```
struct Database
{
   string name;
   string addressPerson; 
}

Database[] public people;

mapping (string => uint) idToPerson;

function setPerson(string _id, string _name, string _address) external {
   people.push(Database(_name,_address));
   idToPerson[_id] = people.length-1;           
}
```

Which should I use and why? I researched a lot and couldn't find an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Which one uses less gas? My assumption would be the first, because it writes one less thing to storage. (Writing to storage is so expensive that other minor differences like hashing or storing something temporarily in memory probably don't matter.) But if you're looking for whichever is cheaper, just try them out and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating sample contracts with the above two approaches. I used **[Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org)** to calculate the costs. Note that these are indicative costs (but still helpful), which could change depending upon many factors.

When you deploy the contract and call the function SetPerson(), it will show you the details of transaction in the bottom pane.

Find out more about [difference between Transaction Cost and Execution Cost here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-browser-so)

**Approach 1** (mapping to object)

- **Contract Deployment**

  transaction cost   **179161** gas

  execution cost     **95141** gas
- **Function call**

  transaction cost     **65441** gas

  execution cost  **41609** gas

---

**Approach 2** (mapping to id, array)

- Contract Deployment:

  transaction cost     **361519** gas

  execution cost   **232075** gas
- Function call

  transaction cost     **91228** gas

  execution cost   **67396** gas

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll take a look on the link you sent. As I'm new to Solidity, I have many questions about costs and things related.