# How do I see how much gas a .call() transaction used in remix IDE connected to ganache-cli?

Tags: remix, gas, ganache

I've got remix connected to ganache-cli and I'm running some read-only transactions. I can't seem to figure out how to see how much gas those transactions used up?

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore the cost like this:

[image]

Have a look over here for a description of transaction cost and execution cost; [What is the difference between transaction cost and execution cost in browser solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-browser-so)

In case it isn't clear, when `view` functions are called, or when a client users the `call()` method (read-only), then the gas cost is returned to the requester. If a `view` (or `pure` or `constant`) function is called from another function or contract, then the cost accrues to the transaction that kicked it off.

More about the subtleties over here: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps.