# What are the gas, transaction cost and execution cost in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

There was a question here [What is the difference between transaction cost and execution cost in remix?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-remix), but when I used Remix, I never see the transaction cost differing from execution cost here?

It's something like:
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    36846 gas
execution cost  36846 gas
when an exception happens, or

gas 86662 gas
transaction cost    75358 gas
execution cost  75358 gas
when the transaction executes without problems?

The transaction cost seems to always equal to the execution cost? And which number is the gas used? If the transaction is executed without problem, the gas number is the real gas used? But in case of an exception, the transaction cost is the gas used?

Comment: It depends on the operation you are doing generally a transaction cost includes an execution cost. So if you are only calling global variables, they are equal and Remix won't print it. It will only print execution cost.