# What is transaction cost why it alway equal execution cost?

Tags: solidity, remix, transactions, gas

I use solidity Remix to build smart contract. I don't understand about transaction cost. why transaction cost alway equal execution cost. Can I change transaction cost different from execution cost ?

Comment: there is a gasLimit parameter in the transaction , i.e. the maximum cost you can spend, and the real gas spent during execution of the contract. that is probably what transaction cost is, the gasLimit parameter. (I don't use Remix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5812/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-cost-and-execution-cost-in-remix) answer:

Transaction costs are based on the cost of sending data to the blockchain. There are 4 items which make up the full transaction cost:

1. the base cost of a transaction (21000 gas)
2. the cost of a contract deployment (32000 gas)
3. the cost for every zero byte of data or code for a transaction.
4. the cost of every non-zero byte of data or code for a transaction.

Execution costs are based on the cost of computational operations which are executed as a result of the transaction.

You can give your upvote to the original author.